# Split git .pack files into smaller packs?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which I have run this on:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

This repository now has a ~5GB .pack file.

I am trying to run a tool which appears to fail to handle files this large. (FYI: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2557)

I'd like to repack the repo's pack files into smaller ones to avoid this bug.

It looks like `git-repack` may do what I want, but it doesn't do anything when run like this:

```
$ git repack --max-pack-size=1g
Nothing new to pack.
```

I can't see any kind of 'force' option. I thought perhaps I needed to unpack first, but the documentation for `git-unpack-file` and `git-unpack-objects` looks a bit low-level.

How can I do this? I think asking the community is the best option here since each 'experiment' I do takes a very long time to run and I may be barking up the wrong tree anyway! Thanks :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did your repository get so big?

Comment: Try `git repack --max-pack-size=1g -a`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Ah - the docs are a bit unclear about that, but you're right - thanks!

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - The repo is tracking a Perforce depot using `git-p4`, and that depot is used for game development - lots of large binary files. I'm taking the plunge and will move it entirely to git+lfs, but I've fallen at the first hurdle ;)

Comment: @BenHymers Yes, the `-a` part in the docs is confusing. I still don't understand why `-a` works.